# ContactsContract: update RawContact ignores display_name

Tags: android, contactscontract

When updating a `ContactsContract.Data` `StructuredName` row for a `RawContact`, my code sets the `DISPLAY_NAME` column with a value provided by the user. It also updates the first, middle, last with values provided by the user.

When fetching the contact `DISPLAY_NAME` back from `ContactsContract.Contacts`, the display name provided to the `RawContact` is ignored and, instead, Android has fabricated one based on the `StructuredName` name parts.

Is there a way to tell `ContactsContract` to use the display name provided?

For example, consider that the following are written to a `StructuredName` row:

```
DISPLAY_NAME: F L
GIVEN_NAME: F
MIDDLE_NAME: X
LAST_NAME: L
```

In this case, I would expect the aggregate contact display name to be "F L". However, it will be "F X L".

Here is the code to write a StructureName row, where the values being set to each column are member variables:

```
protected void prepareUpdate (ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops)
{
  String where = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + dataId;

  ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder;
  builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate (ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
  builder.withSelection (where, null);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, givenName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, familyName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX, prefix);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, middleName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SUFFIX, suffix);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME, phoneticFamilyName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME, phoneticMiddleName);
  builder.withValue (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME, phoneticGivenName);

  ops.add (builder.build());
}
```

Here's the code that executes the "ops":

```
  ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
  ContentProviderResult[] results = resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

And, here's the code to fetch the aggregate contact's display name:

```
public static ContactData fetchContact (Cursor cursor)
{
  String name = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
  ... do something with the feteched data ...
}
```

If Android is ignoring the display name provided by the user, what is the point of that column?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [DISPLAY_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html#DISPLAY_NAME) it says:

> The name that should be used to display the contact. Unstructured
>   component of the name **should be consistent with its structured
>   representation**.

This means that whenever you update `DISPLAY_NAME`, it updates the name parts (`GIVEN_NAME`, etc.), and whenever you update one of the parts, it updates the `DISPLAY_NAME`, so at all times the name parts and the `DISPLAY_NAME` are consistent.

I'm guessing they do this to avoid issues like a user fixes a wrong name set to a phone number from "`John Doe`" to "`Bob Dylan`", but the name parts aren't being updated so they remain with "`John`" and "`Doe`", this is a obviously an undesired situation.

Comment: Thank you, but that is subjective. What does "consistent" mean? And what are the consequences of being inconsistent? They don't explain either. Further, my app successfully saves whatever values the user puts into the structured name parts or the display name. There is no problem at this level. The problem is that the aggregate level is using the name parts, not the display name, to determine the aggregate display name.

Comment: you can experiment with it, try updating just the name parts, and see what happens to the display_name and vice versa... i agree that it is subjective, but it all depends on how the ContactsContract code is written, so at the very least it should be deterministic.

Comment: just another little note - see how Google's contact editor is behaving - you can either edit the display_name, or click on the expand button and only edit the name-parts, it doesn't let you edit both

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Thanks.